# Insert into Oracle from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using ADO object to connect oracle database. When I execute an INSERT statemnet from VBA it is getting inserted properly. If I check the same record with the current connection, I am able to retrieve the inserted data. But when I check the same directly in Oracle it is not reflecting that inserted Data.

For cross verification, I have created one more button to check whether the Data inserted into the ORACLE table. But there I'm getting only zero recrods.

(I have tried with connection method .BeginTrans and cn.CommitTrans before execute statement)

Can any one of you please let me know the reason.

Regards,
Ram

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are missing a `COMMIT` after your `INSERT` statement.

This [article](http://www.nsbasic.com/desktop/info/technotes/TN22.htm) does a

```
objADO.CommitTrans
```

**after** executing the insert.

Comment: Do you call `CommitTrans` **after** inserting? Could you please try the example from the link?

Comment: Hey guys,

Any setting has to be made in the DB side?

Kindly let me know the reason for the same.

Thanks in advance